# Detect Availability of High Quality Voice in Android device

Tags: android, text-to-speech

Is there a way to detect (programmatically) if the user  has downloaded the high quality version of a voice to be used by the TTS Engine? The TextToSpeech.isLanguageAvailable does not seem to have a way to distinguish between the standard engines and the high-quality engines.

e.g

```
TextToSpeech mTts = new TextToSpeech(this, this)
// then if we wish to check if the user has installed a particular locale
// say Spanish
mTts.isLanguageAvailable(new Locale('spa', 'ESP'));
```

The above will return True even if the just released high quality spanish TTS files have not been downloaded by the user. I would like to detect that

Thanks,

- Raj

Comment: Question is too vague

Comment: @RIT: just updated the Question

Comment: I've previously raised this with the Google TTS team, as a high quality download would negate the need for requesting network synthesis. I'll be raising an enhancement request over the coming days and will link back to it here. You may be able to find where the standard install location is and check if it exists - but that's scrappy for production code.

Comment: Thanks @brandall. I also have hit a wall with distinguishing the male and female voices provided with UK English. This, too, has been discussed in this forum. I have an educational app and refer to these voices by Instructor names for better appeal, as in "Emily", "Derek", "Anna" etc